# Unable to inject service in http interceptors

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I need to set up this `HttpInterceptor`? `oidcSecurityService` is not defined.

The `HttpClient` allows you to write interceptors. A common usecase would be to intercept any outgoing HTTP request and add an authorization header. Keep in mind that injecting `OidcSecurityService` into the interceptor via the constructor results in a cyclic dependency. To avoid this use the injector instead.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let requestToForward = req;

        if (this.oidcSecurityService === undefined) {
            this.oidcSecurityService = this.injector.get(OidcSecurityService);
        }
        if (this.oidcSecurityService !== undefined) {
            let token = this.oidcSecurityService.getToken();
            if (token !== '') {
                let tokenValue = 'Bearer ' + token;
                requestToForward = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: tokenValue } });
            }
        } else {
            console.debug('OidcSecurityService undefined: NO auth header!');
        }

        return next.handle(requestToForward);
    }
}
```

This is in my app.module. 
I need to get the `OidcSecurityService` injected.

```js
  providers: [
    OidcSecurityService,
    OidcConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfig,
      deps: [OidcConfigService],
      multi: true
    },   
    AuthorizationGuard,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useClass: AuthInterceptor, 
      multi: true
    }    
  ]
```

Comment: Why don't you injec the service in the constructor? The injector class was used in Angular 4.X due to a bug.

Comment: I'm new to Angular and was using the code that was provided. 
So, I could just inject OidcSecurityService?

Comment: @NicuVlad injecting service in constructor of interceptor causes circular dependency errors most of the times.

Comment: @AnandBhushan, from what I know this was fixed, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48903734/3018671

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this-

```
@Injectable()
            export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
                private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService;

                constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

                intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
                    let requestToForward = req;
                    this.oidcSecurityService = this.injector.get(OidcSecurityService);
                    let token = this.oidcSecurityService.getToken();
                    if (token !== '') {
                        let tokenValue = 'Bearer ' + token;
                        requestToForward = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: tokenValue } });
                    }


                    return next.handle(requestToForward);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This worked. But what? I see you removed the condition checks.

Comment: I didn't find the conditions necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the service directly in the constructor:

```
   constructor(private oidcSecurityService : OidcSecurityService) { }
```

There was a bug regarding the injection of a service in a constructor but this was fixed in:

> Angular 5.2.3 released 31 January 2018

Please check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48903734/3018671